# In which movie was the "Ultimate Question" mentioned for the first time?

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember in which movie it was mentioned for the first time.

It was some movie with John Malkovich if I remember well.

Comment: Which Ultimate Question? Asimov's, Adams', whose?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Malkovich is a bit of an obvious factor to easily narrow it down :)

Comment: @DVK I actualyl don't know who he is, nor have I (to my knowledge) ever seen anything with him in it. So it'd be nice to know. I've just seen the answers, maybe I have seen him....

Comment: @Pureferret - just IMDB him. I'm sure one of his roles will ring a bell :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"[The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/)" was a 2005 movie where John Malkovich played "[Humma Kavula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humma_Kavula#Humma_Kavula)" (Zaphod Beeblebrox's competitor for President of the Galaxy post).

That movie was based on Douglas Adams' "[The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)" book, which famously originated "42" as the "[Ultimate Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)".

The details on the Ultimate question are covered on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Comment: The phrasing "ultimate question" itself looks to have originated with John William Allen in 1644: http://books.google.com/books?id=nqQFAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22ultimate+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F6EZT72XBMeQsQK32OnnCw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22ultimate%20question%22&f=false One of the prettiest Google Ngram plotsd I've seen: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ultimate+question&year_start=1000&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Answer (score 9):

The origin of "The Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything" ( to which the answer is, of course, 42 ) was Douglas Adams Hitchikers Guide series, which first appeared on Radio back in the early 1980s.

That seems like a pretty ultimate question to me. But as @Daniel said, you need to clarify if you want better or other results.

Comment: HHGTG was on BBC radio in 1979, the same year the book was published.

Comment: Thank you - I know it was popular in various forms around that time.

Comment: HHGTG was first on Radio 4 in 1978, not 1979.