# Character leaves singing "When you walk through the storm, hold your head up high…”

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to place a very dimly-remembered scene from a book — which I think was sci-fi/fantasy, though I'm not even 100% sure of that.

Some character is seen bowing out of the main action — I think in a slightly suicidal way, making a last stand against enemies to buy the main group some time, or something. And as she (I think the character was female, but again, I'm not certain) goes, we and the remaining protagonists hear her singing (possibly over a ship's intercom, or something like that) the song

> ["When you walk through the storm / Hold your head up high / And don’t be afraid of the dark…"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4IGlTLXHDg)

**What is the name of this book?**

Comment: You'll never walk alone is a pretty famous song.

Comment: The song was used on episode #1.3 of the TV series of _The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy_.

Comment: @PLL: Roughly when did you read it?

Comment: Maybe the same book as this (unanswered) question on [Loganberry Books: Stump the Bookseller](http://loganberrybooks.com/stump-xyz.html): "Y64: You'll never walk alone from the musical carousel features in this fantasy novel / I read this fantasy novel in the 80's or 90's. There are two protagonists, a boy and a girl, and the song "you'll never walk alone" from the musical "carousel" is a prominent plot point. Very dark"

Comment: @SQB And likewise Mahalia Jackson's "You'll Never Walk Alone" appears in the novel *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*. :)

Comment: @Lexible - Mahalia Jackson just covered the song.  It was written by Rodgers and Hammerstein, and covered by pretty much everyone in the history of ever.

Comment: @WadCheber Oh?. . . Oh, yeah! Thanks for the correct!

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9393/in-which-movie-was-the-ultimate-question-mentioned-for-the-first-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eddie the onboard computer of the starship "The Heart of Gold" sang *You'll Never Walk Alone*<sup>1</sup> just as the ballistic missles were closing in above Magorathea in *The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*.

<sup>1</sup> Written by Rodgers and Hammerstein for the play *Carousel*, and later covered by *Gerry and the Pacemakers*, Judy Garland, Elvis Presley, and many others.

Comment: Eddie is not female, nor *"making a last stand against enemies to buy the main group some time"*

Comment: @Richard: despite those, this is definitely the passage I was thinking of, looking it up and re-reading it.  I guess my memory of it was even dimmer and less accurate than I thought, I’m afraid.

Comment: @Richard Eddie is re-configured with a matronly personality by the time they actually land on Magrathea. Can't remember if it was _explicitly_ female or not. Doesn't change the fact that Eddie is loaded with the male personality at the time of singing but still not entirely irrelevant.