# Title of a movie I watched around 2004~2006: Earth was destroyed and rebuilt, protagonist kills mice

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie when I was a kid so I can't recall anything but a couple of details:

1. The Earth was destroyed but a friend of a protagonist reconstructed it.
2. The protagonist has 2 companions, a woman and an older man
3. There is a gigantic monitor-like thing. I think it was a screen, but it talked to the protagonist
4. The only "full" scene I can remember was the following: The protagonist is in a house with the two companions. There are 2 mice that then make the other two companions sleep and tie up the protagonist. They say that they are going to drill his head or something like that. I can't remember what does he do, but he finally like smashes the mice on the tablecloth but when he lifts his hand, there are 2 angel shapes.

I think that the monitor told the story of two kids that somehow turned into mice or something like that, and that-s when he realizes he killed the two mice.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I have had the doubt for so long and I can't find the movie. Many people tell me it sounds like Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy but I watched it and it wasn't.

[EDIT]: The movie might have been out before the given date, I just remember watching it around that time

Comment: "Many people tell me it sounds like Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy but I watched it and it wasn't." Is it possible that when you went back to watch it to see if it was the one you remembered, you watched the 1981 TV adaptation rather than the 2005 movie adaptation? And if it was the movie that you checked, did you watch it all the way through? In particular did you see the scene with the mice that rand al'thor posted?

Comment: Technically they're not mice. They're highly intelligent pandimensional beings that have an affinity for fromage. (Also, don't say Belgium).

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9393/in-which-movie-was-the-ultimate-question-mentioned-for-the-first-time

Answer (score 16):

This **is** the 2005 film [*Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/), based on the novel and radio show by Douglas Adams. Every detail matches.

> 1- The Earth was destroyed but a friend of a protagonist reconstructed it.

At the start of the film, the Earth is destroyed by Vogons in order to make room for a hyperspace bypass. It is later rebuilt by the same crew who originally constructed it, including Slartibartfast, a friend of the protagonist Arthur Dent.

> 2- The protagonist has 2 companions, a woman and an older man

Arthur travels together with a woman (Trillian) and two men (Ford Prefect and Zaphod Beeblebrox):

[image: trillian]
[image: ford]
[image: zaphod]

He also meets an older man, Slartibartfast, and travels together with him for only a short while:

[image: slartibartfast]

> 3- There is a gigantic monitor-like thing. I think it was a screen, but it talked to the protagonist

This is [Deep Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Deep_Thought), the computer designed to find the Ultimate Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything (the answer being 42). In the film it is "shaped like a massive black metal trapezoid with a yellow rectangular display that blinked on and off in time with the computer's speaking."

> 4- The only "full" scene I can remember was the following: The protagonist is in a house with the two companions. There are 2 mice that then make the other two companions sleep and tie up the protagonist. They say that they are going to drill his head or something like that. I can't remember what does he do, but he finally like smashes the mice on the tablecloth but when he lifts his hand, there are 2 angel shapes.

This is an exact description of a scene towards the end of the film. I'll try to find a Youtube video showing this clip. **Edit**: OK, the best I found was this one, which stops just *before* he smashes the mice. You can see they're about to drill into his head, and Zaphod and Trillian are asleep on the other side of the table:

> Many people tell me it sounds like Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy but I watched it and it wasn't.

Perhaps the HHGTTG you watched which *wasn't* this was the [1981 TV series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081874/) adaptation?

Comment: The older man could also be Zaphod...

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, you're probably right. Particularly as Zaphod is the one who appears in the mice scene.

Comment: @CycloneBender14 Before you watch the movie again, read the books, at least the first 3 of them. While there are good aspects of the movie, it doesn't come close to capturing the humor in the books. The books themselves are based on the radio play, which also spawned a TV miniseries. The latter is cheaply made, but I recommend all of it over the movie.

Comment: I would also recommend the [Dirk Gently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently_%28TV_series%29) series (not that they made terribly many).

Comment: @Hypnosifl, "older" makes me fairly certain that the OP may have recalled Slartibartfast, without remembering that he wasn't a constant companion.